# "IPA Processing Failed" when trying to export project as Ad-Hoc Build with M1 MacBook Air

Tags: build, xcode12, apple-silicon

When I try to export my app as an ad-hoc build, Xcode suddenly displays the error message "IPA Processing Failed". This used to work, does it have something to do with Apple Silicon?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does have to do with Apple Silicon, seems to be an Xcode bug - if you run Xcode with Rosetta, it works. To run Xcode with Rosetta, open a context menu on Xcode.app, go to "Show Info", then check "Run with Rosetta". Now the ad-hoc build works.

Comment: After open using rosetta. I found another issue.. like my all storyboards & XIBs does not load frames. shows Internal error. Cleaning app, deleting derived data, restarting mac nothing worked.

Comment: This looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916429/how-to-fix-ipa-processing-failed-in-xcode-12-2-with-mac-m1?noredirect=1&lq=1 .  I've spent a ton of time looking into this.  I will continue to investigate until I. find a solution.  This far the problem appears related to use of Cocopods Or Carthage in conjunction with the M1.