# Xcode Storyboard is black (An internal error occurred)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a big problem. Since two days Xcode only shows the Storyboards in black like shown below. As you can imagine it is terrible for me as i can not work with the background blacked out.

The error that is shown is "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited."

**Below you can see the Log.txt with the error**

```
    DATE:
=================================

Monday, 1. February 2021 at 21:43:26 Central European Standard Time
2021-02-01 20:43:26 +0000



=================================
    XCODE VERSION INFO:
=================================

Version = 12.4 (12D4e)
Plugin Version = 17701
Beta Version = 1
OS Version = 11.2 (20D64)



=================================
    ERROR:
=================================

Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason: IBAgent-iOS (-1) failed to launch): Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn (Failure reason: Failed to spawn IBAgent-iOS on iPhone Xʀ (0670D6F0-16E0-43A4-9E6E-D2B37DCD777D, iOS 14.4, Booted)): Invalid device state

Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=IBAgent-iOS (-1) failed to launch, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f94b9b4a510 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=405 "Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to spawn IBAgent-iOS on iPhone Xʀ (0670D6F0-16E0-43A4-9E6E-D2B37DCD777D, iOS 14.4, Booted), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f94b9b6f6f0 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=405 "Invalid device state" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device state}}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "IBAgent-iOS" for further information., NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS.}



=================================
    TOOL DESCRIPTION:
=================================

<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7f94af942a40> {
| targetRuntime.identifier: IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater
| _roleString: System content
| deviceTypeDescription: <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7f94aef53f60> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XR
}



=================================
    LAUNCH CONTEXT:
=================================

<IBCocoaTouchToolLaunchContext: 0x7f9519cb45c0> {
| toolDescription.ib_verboseDescription: <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7f94af942a40> {
| | targetRuntime.identifier: IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater
| | _roleString: System content
| | deviceTypeDescription: <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7f94aef53f60> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XR
| }
| launchPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/IBAgent-iOS
| frameworkSearchPaths: (
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks"
)
| toolName: IBAgent-iOS
| platformName: iphonesimulator
| applicationTool: 0
| processIdentifier: -1
| exitStatus: (null)
| signalStatus: (null)
}



=================================
    EXECUTION CONTEXT:
=================================

<IBSimulatorToolCoreSimulatorBootedCLIExecutionContext: 0x7f94aafaa880 busyCount=0, Idle for 0.0 secs> {
| device: iPhone Xʀ (0670D6F0-16E0-43A4-9E6E-D2B37DCD777D, iOS 14.4, Booted)
}



=================================
    DEVICE:
=================================

iPhone Xʀ (0670D6F0-16E0-43A4-9E6E-D2B37DCD777D, iOS 14.4, Booted)



=================================
    TOOL MANAGER:
=================================

<IBCocoaTouchToolManager: 0x7f94aef33af0>



=================================
    REASON FOR REQUESTING TOOL:
=================================

Preflighting tools for opening document <IBStoryboardDocument: 0x7f94bb9ffa00>: <IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime: 0x7f94aef42bd0>



=================================
    XCODE BACKTRACE:
=================================

  0   +[IBPlatformToolFailureHandler failureHandlerWithContext:failure:diagnosticsHandlerBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  1   +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_injectDiagnosticsHandlerWithFailureContext:intoError:forLaunchingToolWithError:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  2   +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:proxyDelegate:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  3   __117-[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager asyncLaunchNewToolWithDescription:queue:completionHandler:forReason:]_block_invoke.429 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   _dispatch_lane_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 10   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)




=================================
    SDKS:
=================================

iOS 14.4 (iphoneos14.4):
version = 14.4
platform = com.apple.platform.iphoneos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "34AA5D88-518E-11EB-91C4-72143A615026";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18D46;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2021 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "14.4";
}

macOS 11.1 (macosx11.1):
version = 11.1
platform = com.apple.platform.macosx
versionInfo = {
    ProductBuildVersion = 20C63;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = macOS;
    ProductUserVisibleVersion = "11.1";
    ProductVersion = "11.1";
    iOSSupportVersion = "14.3";
}

Simulator - iOS 14.4 (iphonesimulator14.4):
version = 14.4
platform = com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "34AA5D88-518E-11EB-91C4-72143A615026";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18D46;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2021 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "14.4";
}

Simulator - watchOS 7.2 (watchsimulator7.2):
version = 7.2
platform = com.apple.platform.watchsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "7.2";
}

watchOS 7.2 (watchos7.2):
version = 7.2
platform = com.apple.platform.watchos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "7.2";
}

Simulator - iOS 14.4 (iphonesimulator14.4):
version = 14.4
platform = com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "34AA5D88-518E-11EB-91C4-72143A615026";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18D46;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2021 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "14.4";
}

tvOS 14.3 (appletvos14.3):
version = 14.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "14.3";
}

tvOS 14.3 (appletvos14.3):
version = 14.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "14.3";
}

Simulator - watchOS 7.2 (watchsimulator7.2):
version = 7.2
platform = com.apple.platform.watchsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "7.2";
}

iOS 14.4 (iphoneos14.4):
version = 14.4
platform = com.apple.platform.iphoneos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "34AA5D88-518E-11EB-91C4-72143A615026";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18D46;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2021 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "14.4";
}

watchOS 7.2 (watchos7.2):
version = 7.2
platform = com.apple.platform.watchos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "8D9D1CD2-32F3-11EB-B18E-209C67F7BDAB";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18S561;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "7.2";
}

Simulator - tvOS 14.3 (appletvsimulator14.3):
version = 14.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "14.3";
}

macOS 11.1 (macosx11.1):
version = 11.1
platform = com.apple.platform.macosx
versionInfo = {
    ProductBuildVersion = 20C63;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = macOS;
    ProductUserVisibleVersion = "11.1";
    ProductVersion = "11.1";
    iOSSupportVersion = "14.3";
}

DriverKit 20.2 (driverkit.macosx20.2):
version = 20.2
platform = com.apple.platform.macosx
versionInfo = {
}

Simulator - tvOS 14.3 (appletvsimulator14.3):
version = 14.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "E3F85AF8-32C4-11EB-9F1B-1F54C5D7F887";
    ProductBuildVersion = 18K559;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2020 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "14.3";
}
```

I already tried to

- update Mac Software
- Update Xcode
- Clean Project
- Close Xcode
- Restart Mac
- set derived Data in Preferences > Locations to Default

The [You can see the black screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di53a.jpg)

It would be very nice if you can help me to solve this.

Thank you very much

max

Comment: There are lots of "the storyboard is black" question/answer pairs on stack overflow already. There is no point asking this again.

Comment: thanks. That also didn't help. I'm using the MacBook Pro with an M1 (2020) and "Open using Rosetta" is checked. I cleaned the project, closed Xcode, restarted the Mac, still nothing has changed.

Answer (score 11):

**Update**: This issue fixed with Xcode 12.5 release

I got this same error today and I tried the ways that you mentioned, but none of them worked. And then I remembered that I checked **"Open using Rosetta"** in **Xcode's "Get Info"**. When I **unchecked** this option, **cleaned** the project, and **reopened Xcode**, it works.

If you are using MB with an M1 chip, I think you can try this.

But I should warn you if you unchecked **"Open using Rosetta"** option, you can get "IPA processing failed" error when you achieve the project. More detail: [How to fix "IPA processing failed" in Xcode 12.2 with MAC M1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64916429/4711785)

Comment: Well, that helped me too.However Disabling Rosetta mode will fail your build also. That's so unfortunate.

Comment: This was the only working method, thank you very much. "cleaned the project, and reopened Xcode" is important.