# IPA processing failed in Xcode when trying to create distribution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, carthage

I am trying to build and create a new IPA file (Enterprise Distribution, not app store) and I am having difficulties.  This is an app that I have not touch for about a year, but need to create new binaries due to expiring cert.

Environment: macOS 10.15.7, Xcode 11.5 (Swift 5.2.4)

I first upgraded to XCode 12.4, but had issues with Swift versions and 3rd party libraries that I use, so I went back to Xcode 11.5.  I am using Carthage and it seems to run fine and Xcode builds fine, but it errors out after clicking on Distribute App: Product -> Archive -> Distribute -> Enterprise/Development -> “IPA processing failed”:

[image: Error Msg]

In the log, I see this about Alamofire, which seems to be the issue:

```
2021-02-18 18:23:00 +0000  Scanning IPA...
2021-02-18 18:23:00 +0000  Assertion failed: Expected 4 archs in otool output:
/var/folders/6_/t3d3774j3k51w0xwhdswhw880000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.~~~UiyRoc/Payload/POS 
Pad.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
```

Carthage libraries:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "5.4.1"
github "AuthorizeNet/sdk-ios" "4.2"
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" "4.2.0"
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" "4.3.0"
github "TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA" "1.6.0"
github "emaloney/CleanroomLogger" "6.0.2"
github "glock45/swifter" "1.5.0"
github "jzau/fpingx" "0.1.2"
```

I have "/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks" in Build Phases (as always).  I have also added the Run Script from here: ['IPA processing failed' while distributing build in Xcode Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881761/ipa-processing-failed-while-distributing-build-in-xcode-beta), but that did not help.

I only need this to run on iPad Air 2 and later (but it would be good if it also runs on the iPad emulators).

*I have never seen this error before and help to get this working would be much appreciated!*

Comment: Bump...  Anybody?